# Using Firebug to watch a code

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm new to programming and are trying to learn javascript, html and css right now. I'm using Firebug to see code and trying to understand it. Found someones
"Hangman Game" that looks pretty cool to be able to do.

However when I try to see how it's done via Firebug I see "strange characters" which make it difficult to really understand everything. Looks like some things have the same variable even though they are different.

So wondering if it's possible to do anything about this?

The code looks like this

```
window.Hangman = function () {
    'use strict';
    var e = {
        partAsElement: {
            hill: document.getElementById('hang_hill'),
            gallow: document.getElementById('hang_construction'),
            body: document.getElementById('hang_body'),
            rightarm: document.getElementById('hang_rightarm'),
            leftarm: document.getElementById('hang_leftarm'),
            rightleg: document.getElementById('hang_rightleg'),
            leftleg: document.getElementById('hang_leftleg'),
            rope: document.getElementById('hang_rope'),
            head: document.getElementById('hang_head')
        },
        validParts: [
            'hill',
            'gallow',
            'rope',
            'head',
            'body',
            'rightarm',
            'leftarm',
            'rightleg',
            'leftleg'
        ],
        ordlista: [
            'FANTASY',
            'NOTHING',
            'INDIGO',
            'NATIVE',
            'FOREARM',
            'NODE',
            'EYESOCKET'
        ],
        strecklista: [
        ],
        usedlista: [
        ],

        k: 0,

        isValid: function (e) {
            return - 1 === this.validParts.indexOf(e) ? (console.log('The part is not valid: ' + e), !1)  : (console.log('The part is valid: ' + e), !0)
        },


        hide: function (e) {
            this.isValid(e) && (console.log('Hiding part: ' + e), this.partAsElement[e].style.display = 'none')
        },


        show: function (e) {
            this.isValid(e) && (console.log('Showing part: ' + e), this.partAsElement[e].style.display = 'inline')
        },


        shuffle: function (e) {
            var t,
            n,
            l;
            for (l = e.length; l; l -= 1) t = Math.floor(Math.random() * l),
            n = e[l - 1],
            e[l - 1] = e[t],
            e[t] = n
        },


        pickWord: function () {
            var e;
            return this.shuffle(this.ordlista),
            e = this.ordlista[0],
            console.log(e),
            e
        },
        drawUnderscore: function (e) {
            var t,
            n,
            l;
            for (console.log(e), t = document.getElementById('streck'), n = 0; n < e.length; n++) this.strecklista.push('_');
            return l = this.strecklista.join(' '),
            t.innerHTML = l,
            l
        },
        'klickaVälj': function (n) {
            var l,
            o,
            s,
            a,
            i,
            r;
            l = document.getElementsByClassName('bokstav'),
            s = document.getElementById('streck'),
            a = document.getElementById('used'),
            l[n].addEventListener('click', function () {
                for (l[n].classList.add('selected'), o = this.innerHTML, i = 0, r = 0, n = 0; n < t.length; n++) t[n] === o ? (console.log(t[n]), e.strecklista[n] = o)  : (console.log('bokstaven finns inte på plats ' + n), i++);
                for (console.log('j = ' + i), console.log(e.strecklista), n = 0; n < e.strecklista.length; n++) '_' === e.strecklista[n] && (r++, console.log(r));
                s.innerHTML = e.strecklista.join(' '),
                0 === r && window.alert('You won!'),
                console.log(e.k),
                i === t.length && (console.log('utför andra if-satsen'), e.usedlista.push(o), console.log('usedlista' + e.usedlista), e.show(e.validParts[e.k]), e.k++, e.k === e.validParts.length && window.alert('You lost!')),
                a.innerHTML = e.usedlista
            })
        },
        addClick: function () {
            var e;
            e = document.getElementsByClassName('bokstav');
            for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++) this.klickaVälj(t)
        }
    },
    t = e.pickWord();
    return e.drawUnderscore(t),
    console.log(t),
    console.log('You can now use the hangman object as a part of the window-object. Try\n\nwindow.Hangman.hide(\'gallow\')\nwindow.Hangman.show(\'gallow\')\n\nHere are all the parts you can work on.'),
    console.log(e.validParts),
    e
}();
```

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/8c34noqf/ (from what I can see they use 2 js-files and I can only paste one of them). So here's the other one

```
!function () {
    'use strict';
    function n() {
        for (a = 0; a < i.length; a++) window.Hangman.hide(i[a])
    }
    var a,
    i;
    i = window.Hangman.validParts,
    n(),
    window.Hangman.addClick()
}();
```

Comment: yes this is the actual code running behidn the hangman game

Comment: could you please provide a JSFiddle or Plunker demo. That would be really helpful.

Comment: *"I see "strange characters""* Such as?

Comment: Aha ok, just looks odd to me using letters like "e", "l" etc and not real words for the variables. And then using same variable names in other functions doesn't look very "smart". "Strange characters" meaning weird variable names with just one letter instead of maybe naming it to something that's more easy to remember.

Comment: Single letter variable names are very common in minified code (Code which as been optimised to a smaller file size, cutting out unnecessary bytes, mostly to make pages load faster) In general people don't use single character var names in their development code, but run it through a minifier once development is complete.

Comment: Aha ok, thank's for that DBS!